# What tells make that a file is an intermediate file (and can be auto removed)?

Tags: make, c

I'm simply studying make. And I stumble upon the question on make's autoremoving intermediate file. I'd like to better predict how make would mark file intermediate (i.e. answer "Would auto remove it?"), so I wrote a dummy project like this to demonstrate my question:

hello.h

```c
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H
void hello(const char *name);
#endif
```

hello.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(const char *name) {
    printf("Hello %s\n", name);
}
```

main.c

```c
#include "hello.h"
int main() {
    hello("world");
    return 0;
}
```

makefile

```makefile
all: main
    ./main

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.a
    rm -f main

hello.o:
    gcc -c hello.c

libmyhello.a: hello.o
    ar -crv $@ hello.o

main: libmyhello.a
    gcc -L. -o $@ $@.c -lmyhello

.PHONY: all clean
```

When I make `main`, it requires `libmyhello.a`. `libmyhello.a` requires `hello.o`. If I understand it right, `hello.o` should be an intermediate file. But it was **not deleted** in the `make main` process.

Why is it? How to tell if make will treat a file an intermediate file and remove it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. 1. Why do you want to have the file `hello.o` removed? This would lead to running more commands if the library has to be re-built. 2. A Makefile rule should normally specify a target, its prerequisites and the recipe to build the target from the prerequisites. In your Makefile, the rule for `hello.o` lacks `hello.c` as prerequisite, the rule for `main` lacks `main.c` as prerequisite. With these errors `make` might not work when files changed. I suggest to read https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/ and https://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/

Comment: Just want to learn the internals of make. The project really doesn't matter. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intermediate files are only produced by default in chains of implicit rules, and only if they are *not* mentioned explicitly, either as targets or as prerequisites. In your case, all the files you produce are mentioned explicitly in the Makefile, so they aren’t intermediate files.

You can force a file to be an intermediate file by listing it as a prerequisite of `.INTERMEDIATE`:

```
.INTERMEDIATE: hello.o
```

This will result in more work in general since any rebuild of `libmyhello.a` will require rebuilding `hello.o`, even if `hello.c` hasn’t changed. (Incidentally, you should list `hello.c` as a prerequisite of `hello.o`.)

See [the section on intermediate files in chained implicite rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#index-intermediate-files) in the GNU Make manual for details.